# evaluate numeric part of a "sym" variable

Tags: matlab, eval, symbolic-math, maple

I need to evaluate numeric part of a "sym" variable in MATLAB(something like "evalf" function in maple) for instance I have this sym variable :

(12*(51*EE*II - 8*39^(1/2)*EE*II))/(AA*ll^4*ro)

"evalf" in maple gives me 12.48019224*EE*II/(AA*ll^4*ro), is there any way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're looking for the [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) (variable precision arithmetic) function

```
syms EE II AA ll ro
y = (12*(51*EE*II - 8*39^(1/2)*EE*II))/(AA*ll^4*ro)
vpa(y)
```

which returns

```
ans =

(12.48019215375377223869826038978*EE*II)/(AA*ll^4*ro)
```

Comment: I did not know about the `vpa` function. Seems to be exactly what @Alexander1991 is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has a `simplify` command, but keep in mind that the symbolic toolbox does not like to evaluate to give decimal, it will try to keep everything in fractional values, since that is more accurate anyway.

```
syms('EE','AA','ll','II','ro')
simplify((12*(51*EE*II - 8*39^(1/2)*EE*II))/(AA*ll^4*ro)))
```

This will reduce down into the following

```
-(12*EE*II*(8*39^(1/2) - 51))/(AA*ll^4*ro)
```

Whether this is more to your liking is really up to you, but I would suggest keeping things in fractions as opposed to decimal. More accuracy is better.

The `eval` function might also be of some use to you, but that too will keep it fractional. Using that will give you

```
(13722116389931*EE*II)/(1099511627776*AA*ll^4*ro)
```

Comment: Are you using an older version of Matlab? `eval` doest appear to have that behavior anymore. Note that the fractions are approximations of transcendental functions so they're not necessarily more accurate than the symbolic decimal representation. Both are based on the value of `digits`.

Comment: @horchler I am using R2012b. They may have removed that functionality. Of course it is not always more accurate. Just imagine though that it does reduce into 1/3 or something similar, obviously that is more accurate than 0.3333 or whatever.